# c namespaces constuctor argument in spring: Attribute c:_ is not allowed here

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create a bean in spring xml configuration file using `c` namespaces. 
The bean which I'm trying to create has an empty constructor and one String parameter constructor ([`org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQQueue.html)).
When I'm using the following code:

```
<bean id="queue" 
      class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
      c:_="spitter.queue" />
```

Intellij IDEA highlights `c:_` in a red color saying:

> Attribute c:_" is not allowed here

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: <bean id="queue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" c:_="spitter.queue" />

Comment: Use `c:name="spitter.queue"` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the `c` namespace quite right. You should either use indexed arguments like:

```
<bean id="queue"  
      class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
      c:_0="spitter.queue" />
```

Or named arguments:

```
<bean id="queue" 
      class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
      c:name="spitter.queue" />
```

Checkout the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-c-namespace) for more information.

Comment: Should have really linked to the correct doc page, if you are linking in the first place.

Comment: @rents Spring documentation has been redesigned. Anyway, I fixed the link Thanks.